# Sharepoint App or List Read Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I have created an app in Sharepoint. It's a Sharepoint hosted app and i'm trying to make the list or app read only. I know with servideside code it's possible but with clientside code i cannot find a solution.

Is this possible with javascript or jquery?

I have searched the web for a solution but can't find one.

Kind Regards,

Kris

Answer (score 0):

Stop inheriting permissions and give yourself (an admin account) full rights. Remove all other permissions and give everyone read permission.

Comment: how can this be done with javascript or jquery in a sharepoint hosted app ?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSOM [SP.SecurableObject.breakRoleInheritance method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee659518%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to create unique role assignments for the List object and set `copyRoleAssignments` argument to `False` in order to clear role assignments for a List.

Example

```
var listTitle = 'Documents';

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
var web = context.get_web();    
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
list.breakRoleInheritance(false);
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function () {            

   },
   function (sender, args) {
      console.log(args.get_message());
   }
);
```